# How to export views in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

How can i export only views in oracle using export command??

I can able to export entire data base using this command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup view and some tables in oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358681/how-to-backup-view-and-some-tables-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3):

With EXPDP, that's EXPORT DATA PUMP, you can export only views:

```
expdp user/pass DUMPFILE=file.dmp DIRECTORY=ext_tab_dir SCHEMAS=test INCLUDE=VIEW
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Views are included in a user-level or full export, but there is no way to export only the views.

If you just need the view definitions, but not necessarily in export dump format, you can for example get them via `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`. That will not include the grants, however.