# How to backup view and some tables in oracle?

Tags: oracle, dump

I have an Oracle database. On the database There are three tables (a,b,c tables) and a view (union of a and b tables).

I want to backup of a dan b tables and also the view. I used this syntax `exp user/psw file=backup.dmp tables=(a,b)` ,but it doesnt backup the view,only the table.
How can i include the view to be backed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 10g onward, `expdp` is standard export command and `exp` is deprecated.

`expdp` has `include` clause where in you can specify tables and views you want to export. Here is a sample command.

```
expdp scott/tiger@mydb schemas=MYSCHEMA
 include=TABLE:"IN ('A', 'B','C')",VIEW:"IN('my_view')"  
 directory=MY_DIR dumpfile=Exp_ABC_MyView.dmp logfile=expdpExp_ABC_MyView.log
```

Further you can export only object definitions or data or both as well.
more examples in https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

Comment: thank You very much. I implemented using the actual tables and views like this :
`expdp blacklizard/pswd@mydb schemas=blacklizard include=TABLE:" IN ('DEPARTEMEN1','DEPARTEMEN2','DEPARTEMEN3','DEPARTEMEN4',...,'DEPARTEMEN20')",VIEW: " IN ('VIEW_DEPARTEMEN1','VIEW_DEPARTEMEN2','VIEW_DEPARTEMEN3','VIEW_DEPARTEMEN4',...,'VIEW_DEPARTEMEN20')" directory=exp_loc dumpfile=try.dmp logfile=try.log`, but appears an error `UDE-00014: invalid value for parameter, 'include'.`

Comment: Its most likely issue with double quotes. Your operating system might be stripping them while passing it to expdp as arguments. Try syntax as shown in the link I shared in answer . Something like `include=TABLE:\"IN (\'EMP\', \'DEPT\')\"` using `\ to escape "` characters. If not you can simply give expdp as command and it will ask you questions which can be answered to get correct export data set.

Comment: I tested them on Microsoft command prompt, both of below syntax work. `system/********@xe schemas=platformall include=TABLE:IN('DIM_DIM'),VIEW:IN('ALL_DD') dumpfile=test4.dmp` and `system/********@xe schemas=platformall include=TABLE:\"IN(\'DIM_DIM\')\",VIEW:\"IN(\'ALL_DD\')\" dumpfile=test5.dmp`

Comment: How the rules put '\' ?

Comment: @flyingbird013 You need to ensure that double quotes and single quotes must reach expdp command. In linux based operating systems, you must escape both single quotes and double quotes , otherwise they don't play nice when you fire command from shell prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can not include a view to be backed up while using the "exp" utility. Oracle's [expdp](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#i1007837) utility provides option to include views while exporting.

Answer (score -2):

Use imp commnad with this parameters

```
imp user/pass@service file=dumpfile.dmp log=logfile.log full=y rows=n  ignore=n grants=n indexes=n
```